# How to track path direction in android?

Tags: android, path, runtime, tracking, direction

I am having a View class where I am drawing paths through finger touch(bitmaps and canvas). I need to keep track of the direction of path while my finger is moving  on it. Android developer page doesn't give much information on Path.Direction. Any help with this?

Comment: what do u mean by  "track of the direction" ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.Direction.html

Comment: I don't know if its possible to know if its going clockwise or anticlockwise while my finger moves along the view....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an OnMotionEvent listener to your view and either use a [Gesture Detector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) or manually work out the difference in X and Y axis and track the movement yourself

Comment: Yeah.. I have a event listener as I am doing some pixel manipulation.. Will try for Gesture detector.. thanks .:)